# Defining acceleration in gravity-free space

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, reference-frames, observers, equivalence-principle

Without information from outside a closed spaceship, an astronaut cannot distinguish **A** from **B**.

**A)** In gravity-free space, the floor accelerates upwards at $a=g$ and hits a dropped watch.

**B)** On earth's surface, a dropped watch accelerates downwards at $a=g$ and hits the floor.

My question is, what is the acceleration relative to in **A**?  Since acceleration is the second derivative of displacement with respect to time, what is the displacement relative to?  If no other object is used to define the displacement then how can we know the spaceship is accelerating?  If another object is used to define displacement, then wouldn't there be a gravitational force affecting the spaceship, if only weakly?  The concept of "inertial reference frame" seems like circular logic in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, what is the acceleration relative to in **A**?

Acceleration isn't relative, it's absolute. You can detect it with an accelerometer.

> If another object is used to define displacement, then wouldn't there be a gravitational force affecting the spaceship, if only weakly?

One way to build an accelerometer is to use a free-falling test mass as your other object. The gravitational effect can be made as small as desired by making the test mass small enough.